# Can a person enter the USA from Canada at the land border carrying fresh produce grown in the USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, borders

I am reviewing the permissible items allowed for Canadians to carry into the USA across the border.

The [following list](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/resources/traveler/intl-travel/travelers-canada/traveler-canada-fruits-veg/traveler-canada-fv) emphasises that to carry produce into the USA from Canada you have to be able to prove it was grown in Canada. This page does not provide any guidance on produce grown in the USA. It would seem logical to assume that I could bring US produce back into the US, but it is not made clear, so I am not sure.

Comment: "Travelers may not bring U.S.-grown produce they previously brought into Canada back across the border unless the items are whole and still in their original packaging, and any item." Do you have a more specific or general scenerio in mind?

Comment: Where did you get this statement from?

Comment: From your linked page.

Answer (score 4):

From [this page](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/resources/traveler/intl-travel/travelers-canada/traveler-canada-fruits-veg/traveler-canada-fv), expanding the tab "Fresh Produce that you CAN Bring to U.S.":

> Travelers may not bring U.S.-grown produce they previously brought into Canada back across the border unless the items are whole and still in their original packaging, and any item listed in "Fresh Produce that you CANNOT Bring into U.S." panel below—such as citrus, tomatoes, or peppers—even if U.S.-grown, may not re-enter the United States.  Note: U.S. Customs and Border Protection agriculture specialists at the border will make the final determination as to what products may enter.

Comment: So I guess I can bring a US fruit that is also a permitted Canadian fruit, as long as I don't take a bite first....lol ok.

Comment: Watch out for US lemons, oranges and grapefruits though! Since they are all citruses they will confiscate them immediately at the border (it has happened to me) even if they are still in their original packaging. I still believe it doesn't make any sense, since they were grown in the US, exported to Canada and now you are only bringing them back where they came from...